# How is this ES6 function declaration valid?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

How is this function declaration valid in ES6? What does it mean? I've found it in the source code of a React Native project.

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'React';
// some more imports...

function setup():React.Component {

    class Root extends Component {

        // constructor and render functions...   

    }
    return Root
}

export default setup;
```

I have removed a few lines that are not important to see my issue.

I could not find anything related to ES6 or Javascript regarding function declaration followed by a colon.

Comment: simple: it's not valid syntax. it's React, not "just ES6"... Paste into https://babeljs.io/repl/ and uncheck "react" to verify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code is typed with [flow](https://flowtype.org/), Facebook's static type checker (akin to TypeScript). It's not valid ES6, it's a superset of the ES6 syntax.